# Client secrets were invalid

Tags: python, azure, google-api, analytics, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to access Google Analytics API and I'm constantly getting this error with my client_secrets file:

> SystemExit: The client secrets were invalid: 
>      Invalid file format. See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets Expected a JSON object with a single property for a "web" or "installed" application

Here some of my code where I'm using this file. I'm already aware that it is a JSON file itself.

```
flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
          CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH, scope=SCOPES,
          message=tools.message_if_missing(CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH))

storage = file.Storage('analyticsreporting.dat')
credentials = storage.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
  credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
http = credentials.authorize(http=httplib2.Http())
```

Comment: When you created the client in Google developer console which type did you create? I would also check CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH to make sure that is the path to the client secret json file you downloaded from google developer console

Comment: The path is correct, althought it is stored on an azure's adls.

Comment: then i would make sure that your application has access to that path.  Have it open the file and log the contents and check the log.  I would still double check that you have a service account json file and the file from a different client type.

Comment: I can read the file correctly from the code, and it has the following content:
    {
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "XXXX",
  "private_key_id": "XXXXXX",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\XXXXX\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "X@XXX.com",
  "client_id": "XXX",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/XXXX.com"
    }